# JqGrid gives wrong result of number of records,number of pages and rowNum when used filter toolbar

Tags: jqgrid

In my app, I am using JQGrid to render the data in Grid.

In this case, my Grid is set to `loadonce:true` and It also provides filter toolbar facility.

My problem is, I am getting wrong count of total number of pages,total number of records and rowNum of the grid when i have used filter toolbar.

For example : My grid is having total 14 records and rowNum = 5. So there are total 3 pages as displayed in below image.

[image]

Now the code below works fine for me in normal case (case in which I have not used filters toolbar).

```
var records =  $('#list10').getGridParam('records');
var rowNum =  $('#list10').getGridParam('rowNum');
var pageCount = Math.ceil( parseInt(records) / parseInt(rowNum));
```

But When I used filters the above written code is not giving me updated result. Consider the image below for example ..
[image]

Here for this case the above mentioned code gives me same result as .. total pages =3 , total number of rows =14 and rowNum = 5.

Can anyone suggest me that How can I retrieve the updated value of page,total,records,rowNum when I have used filter toolbar ??